# How to exclude .html extension in React router path?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, health-check

I'm creating a simple healthcheck for my app. So far I've created it like this:

Routes:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/" history={history}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="health-check.html" element={<HealthCheck />} /> //THIS IS MY HEALTHCHECK PAGE
        <Route element={<MainLayout pathname={history.location.pathname} />}>
          <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="app/reports/*" element={<PrivateRoute component={Reports} />} />
          <Route path="app/builder" element={<PrivateRoute component={Builder} />}>
            <Route path="" element={<Navigate to="categories" replace />} />
            <Route path="categories" element={<PrivateRoute component={Categories} />} />
            <Route path="categories/:reportingCategoryId" element={<PrivateRoute component={CommentariesList} />} />
            <Route path="commentaries/new" element={<PrivateRoute component={CommentaryNew} />} />
            <Route path="commentaries/:commentaryId" element={<PrivateRoute component={CommentaryEdit} />} />
            <Route path="slider" element={<PrivateRoute component={Slider} />} />
            <Route path="uwec" element={<PrivateRoute component={WeeklyCalendar} />} />
            <Route path="return-expectations-chart" element={<PrivateRoute component={ReturnExpectationsChart} />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>

        <Route path="*" element={<RedirectToApp />} />
      </Routes>
```

Healthcheck component:

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router'

const HealthCheck = () => <Navigate to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/healthcheck.html'} />

export default HealthCheck
```

And the healtcheck.html in my public folder that simply returns harcoded text:

```
status:200
```

All seems fine with these structure but the problem is I need to access the healthcheck url like this **myurl.com/healthcheck.html**

Unless I append the html extension at the end that's the only way I can access the page. If I modify my path in my routes to like this one, without the .html extension, then I get 404 not found.

```
<Route path="health-check" element={<HealthCheck />} /> //THIS IS MY HEALTHCHECK PAGE
```

As much as possible I'd like my path to be just /healthcheck, without the html extension. By the way I made use of plain html file in the public folder so that my healthcheck page will not use bootstrap style. Thanks of any help.

Comment: Why bother adding this to your router?

Comment: You have /public/health-check.html , and navigating to this file, and wants to remove .html from url ?

Comment: @RiTeSh, yes. Actually what I want is to make use of the react router so it's consistent with my current structure. When I access /healthcheck it should show a plain html file withoout any design, because I just create a react component for this, bootstrap design also affects the component which I don't want.

Comment: @Phil, so I can make use of /healthcheck , without the html extension

Comment: In react it's not possible directly,,   but if you are hosting your react project in apache server then you can hide .html by .htaccess file, or different setup in nginx.       Or you can try by giving layout in paths,,, and disable layout for health check components.

Comment: Why not just name the file `public/healthcheck` with no extension?

Comment: @phil, I have not tried that. Would it be fine though? In terms of web standards or sort of